# ¿Cómo evitar mover un objeto que era un argumento de otro cuando uso uno de los métodos del segundo?

Tags: java

Tengo una clase Point y una clase Circle. El constructor de Circle definido como un punto (centro) y un radio.

```
class Point{
    private int x;
    private int y;


    public Point(int px, int py) {
        this.x = px;  // Set the initial value for the class attribute x
        this.y = py;
     }

    public int getx(){
        return this.x;
    }

    public void setx(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int gety(){
        return this.y;
    }

    public void sety(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean isSameAs(Point p1, Point p2){
        if ((p1.x == p2.x) && (p1.y == p2.y)){
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public void translate(int dx, int dy){
        this.x = x+dx;
        this.y = y +dy;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Point p=new Point(1,2);
        Circle c=new Circle(p,1);
        Circle c2=new Circle(p,2);
        c2.translate(1,1);
        System.out.println(c+" "+c2);
    }

}
class Circle{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int r;


    public Circle(Point p, int r) {
        this.x = p.getx();  // Set the initial value for the class attribute x
        this.y = p.gety();
        this.r = r;
     }


    public void translate(int dx, int dy){
        this.x = x+dx;
        this.y = y +dy;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return("Circle of coordinate " + this.x + ", "+ this.y+ " and of radius " + this.r + "\n");
    }

}
```

El problema es que cuando movemos el círculo c1 movimos su punto. En efecto obtengo:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Julien>java Point
Circle of coordinate 1, 2 and of radius 1
 Circle of coordinate 2, 3 and of radius 2
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, en tu método translate(int, int) incrementas el valor de x e y.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu pregunta se debe a un fallo de concepto, te pido disculpas de antemano si estoy equivocado.

```
    this.x = p.getx();
    this.y = p.gety();
    this.r = r;
```

es decir, coges el valor número de de p.getx() y se lo asignas a un nuevo atributo "x", y haces lo mismo con p.getY().

```
    public void translate(int dx, int dy){
    this.x = x+dx;
    this.y = y +dy;
}
```

En este método incrementas el valor de los atributos x e y de tu clase Circle, tu objeto de la clase Punto p, sigue teniendo los valores intactos y puedes acceder a ellos con sus métodos get.